# Run remote python script

Tags: python

Its perhaps not the safest thing in the world to do, but assuming risks have been accounted for, what's the simplest way to load an run a python script that is http(s) hosted, from the local machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# python 2
from urllib import urlopen
# python 3
from urllib.request import urlopen

page = urlopen('https://DANGEROUS').read()
exec(the_page)
```

EDIT: @jakekimds was right to point out that `exec` is more appropriate than `eval` here.

Comment: `exec` is better for this purpose.

Comment: That said, what is your expected use-case? Most use-cases should be possible without `eval`/`exec`.